# CakePHP error log - can I exclude 404 errors?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

The error log of my CakePHP app is full of 404 errors.  Can I exclude these `MissingControllerException`s from appearing in the error log?  Using Cake 2.3.

Comment: Ignoring the errors would pretty much be the ostrich approach. They're thrown for a reason. Apparently your application has broken links in them and they're clicked by your users. Might be something you'd want to fix.

Comment: @Oldskool - the errors are mainly for resources that existed on a previous version of the site but no longer exist. In these cases, there is no relevant new place to redirect to, and redirecting to the homepage would be confusing, so the 404 is not really an error I want to know about.

Comment: Unless you are not using the proper Helpers, missing resources should not trigger a `MissingControllerException`. Either way, to catch any of the "old" URLs, you should use Routes to rewrite them to their new location (or a custom 404 page informing the user they're using outdated links) instead of surpressing exceptions.

Comment: I am talking about old URLs that existed before the site was a CakePHP app, particularly image files.  For example, /images/sm/image.jpg.  There is no "new location" for this image.  If I can stop URLs like this from triggering a MissingControllerException then I would be very happy (though I am not going to put in a redirect for every one of these files, as there are hundreds!)

Comment: I understand that, but you don't have to create a rule for every individual image. You could for example just rewrite all the old image links and still keep a proper working Exception system. For example, in your `app/webroot/.htaccess`, before the Cake "overall" rewrite, just add: `RewriteRule ^images/.* - [L,R=404]`. That will instantly throw a 404 from Apache (so Cake isn't doing anything with it).

Comment: PHP, Will?  Am disappoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply redirecting or removing these URLs is not going to cut it.

A busy site will get hit by hundreds of "random" 404s every day, most from far east countries checking for exploits or URLs such as "/wp-admin".

Logging these with a full stack trace is completely unnecessary

### Solution

You can override the default error handler in CakePHP, and log to `app/tmp/logs/404.log` instead.

In your `app/Config/core.php` file, define the class you want to handle exceptions:

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'MyCustomErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'trace' => true
));
```

Create the class within `app/Lib/Error` and include using `App::uses` in your `app/Config/bootstrap.php` file:

```
App::uses('MyCustomErrorHandler', 'Lib/Error');
```

Make an exact copy of the original ErrorHandler class, just change the class name, and somewhere within the handleException method check which exception is being thrown, and log somewhere else. It will look a bit like this;

```
App::uses('ErrorHandler', 'Error');

class MyCustomErrorHandler {

    public static function handleException(Exception $exception) {

         // some code...

         if (in_array(get_class($exception), array('MissingControllerException', 'MissingActionException', 'PrivateActionException', 'NotFoundException'))) {
             $log = '404';
             $message = sprintf("[%s]", get_class($exception));
         }

         // more code...
    }

}
```

Comment: Finally got round to implementing this and it works well, except I had to change the config for Exception, not Error.  Also instead of copying the whole file I just extended it.

Answer (score 14):

versions above 2.4 (as mentioned by null) have an undocumented feature for this purpose.

just modify your exception config:

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true,
    'skipLog'=>array(
        'MissingControllerException'
    )
));
```

skipLog takes names of exception classes to be excluded from log.

Comment: It is mentionned in the [2.4 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-4-migration-guide.html). `New configuration option skipLog has been added, to allow skipping certain Exception types to be logged. Configure::write('Exception.skipLog', array('NotFoundException', 'ForbiddenException')); will avoid these exceptions and the ones extending them to be be logged when 'Exception.log' config is true`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!

Comment: +1: for busy sites, this solution may be better (not generalizing) because error logs require filewriting. this wont sit good for servers with limited resources.

Answer (score 8):

Building on robmcvey's solution, here is what I had to do for CakePHP 2.6.

### Configuration

In `app/Config/core.php` update the Exception configuration:

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'AppErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

In `app/Config/bootstrap.php` add a CakeLog configuration:

```
CakeLog::config('not_found', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('404'),
    'file' => '404',
));
```

The `type` of `404` is the logging level it will listen in on for anything being written to logs e.g. `CakeLog::write('404', 'That was not found.');`

### Extend ErrorHandler

Create the file `app/Lib/Error/AppErrorHandler.php`. Here we will extend Cake's `ErrorHandler`, overwritting three methods; `handleException()`, `_getMessage()`, and `_log()`.

```
<?php
class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

/**
 * List of Cake Exception classes to record to specified log level.
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected static $_exceptionClasses = array(
        'MissingControllerException' => '404',
        'MissingActionException' => '404',
        'PrivateActionException' => '404',
        'NotFoundException' => '404'
    );

    public static function handleException(Exception $exception) {
        $config = Configure::read('Exception');
        self::_log($exception, $config);

        $renderer = isset($config['renderer']) ? $config['renderer'] : 'ExceptionRenderer';
        if ($renderer !== 'ExceptionRenderer') {
            list($plugin, $renderer) = pluginSplit($renderer, true);
            App::uses($renderer, $plugin . 'Error');
        }
        try {
            $error = new $renderer($exception);
            $error->render();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            set_error_handler(Configure::read('Error.handler')); // Should be using configured ErrorHandler
            Configure::write('Error.trace', false); // trace is useless here since it's internal
            $message = sprintf("[%s] %s\n%s", // Keeping same message format
                get_class($e),
                $e->getMessage(),
                $e->getTraceAsString()
            );

            self::$_bailExceptionRendering = true;
            trigger_error($message, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

/**
 * Generates a formatted error message
 *
 * @param Exception $exception Exception instance
 * @return string Formatted message
 */
    protected static function _getMessage($exception) {
        $message = '';
        if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
            $request = Router::getRequest();
            if ($request) {
                $message .= $request->here() . " Not Found";
            }
        }
        $message .= "\nStack Trace:\n" . $exception->getTraceAsString() . "\n";
        return $message;
    }

/**
 * Handles exception logging
 *
 * @param Exception $exception The exception to render.
 * @param array $config An array of configuration for logging.
 * @return bool
 */
    protected static function _log(Exception $exception, $config) {
        if (!empty(self::$_exceptionClasses)) {
            foreach ((array)self::$_exceptionClasses as $class => $level) {
                if ($exception instanceof $class) {
                    return CakeLog::write($level, self::_getMessage($exception));
                }
            }
        }
        return parent::_log();
    }
}
```

You can customize the `$_exceptionClasses` array to catch which exceptions you want and send them to different logs. The `_getMessage()` method has been simplified to remove the attributes.

### Result

Random URLs like `/exploitable-plugin` will now log to `tmp/logs/404.log`.

```
2015-04-01 16:37:54 404: /exploitable-plugin Not Found
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/example.com/app/index.php(146): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

Comment: Worked great, but also needed to add `App::uses('MyCustomErrorHandler', 'Lib/Error');` inside core.php above where we defined the Exception configuration.

Comment: To clarify isick's comment, if you added `AppErrorHandler` as your new handler, you should add `App::uses('AppErrorHandler', 'Lib/Error');` -- not "MyCustomErrorHandler"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your viewers hit those pages from results of search engines. Since you're a webmaster of this page, you could try to use something like **Google removal tools** https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals . So there won't be any more liks to these pages. It is a little costly in time, but I don't see a way to exclude missing controller actions form logging.

Anyway here you have everything on logging in CakePHP: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1

Edit:

Actually I'd found a way, but it might make you trouble in the future if you forgot about it. Add this to the end of bootstrap.php :

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^\/(.+?)\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$matches);
if(!App::import('Controller', $matches[1])){
   die('404 Error![some_random_chars_so_you_can_easy_find_it_in_the_future]') ;
}
```